# Example ill-conditioned nonlinear system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I need ill-conditioned multivariate nonlinear systems of equations for testing purposes of a computer program.
Do u know any specific problems from science?
I read about chebyschev polynoms, but they are only one-dimensional.

Thank you

Greetings,
Howard

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

$$x^2 − 2x + 3y = − 1 \\
2x^2 - 3.9999x + 6.0001y = - 1.9999$$